# jquery multiselect - binding to knockout issue

Tags: knockout.js, multi-select, custom-binding

I am having issues with using [Eric Hynds excellent multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) with Knockout.

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Uqwn/).

I'm using a custom binding from [this article](http://darkroastjava.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/using-eric-hynds-multiselect-with-knockout/).

If you change the option in the first box, the multi-select reverts to the default type instead of using the plugin - I'm guessing I need to modify the binding, but I'm fairly new to Knockout and rapidly getting out of my depth here.

Can anyone suggest any pointers - any articles on how to write custom bindings may be useful to if anyone has any references handy other than this one of course.

OK: I'm a bit closer: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Uqwn/2/)

Now the only issue is that whenever you change the selection in the first box, you lose any items from the 2nd that are still relevant - also there is some odd behaviour for instance if you:

1. Select "All Link Health"
2. Click the multiselect and check the first item
3. Select "All Watches"
4. Select "All Link Health" again

then you suddenly have all 5 items checked!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found that knockout 2.1.0 not filling "value" attribute to  tag by default, so all options in underlying control will be selected after you check one item because all values are equal to empty. You need to define "optionsValue" in your binding.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to do this, although not convinced I have the best approach.

I wasn't able to manage it at all using "with: ReportTemplate" in the multiple selects where ReportTemplate is the selected item in the first box.

I got a bit closer with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Quu4f/38/) approach - but you get odd behaviour if you Select "All Link Health" in the first combo, and then in the bottom multi-select control, check the box next to Details, and then switch back to the "All Watches" - the bottom multi-select still shows 5 columns available, whereas the top multi-select correctly shows the 3 available ones.

In the end I've adopted the approach of having a subscribe function to update the options available to the select lists: Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BW637/1/). This feels a little clumsy but it's the only method I've found that works as required.

If anyone can explain why the other approaches don't work I'd be interested.